# Netbeans Clean & build classes

Tags: java, file, netbeans, jar

When I clean and build a project in NetBeans, the .jar file appears in the dist folder, like it's supposed to. But what if I have multiple files under the project? What happens to those files? E.g. I have a Game project, and under it are the different characters(knight, rogue, etc.) but I only see a game.jar file when I clean and build, I want to know what happens to the individual files. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those files should be in the jar file as compiled .class files.  It's easy to double check what's in the jar file since it's in zip format.  You can use a program like [7-Zip](http://7-zip.org/) to open it, or rename it to the zip extension (e.g. from mygame.jar to mygame.zip) and whatever OS you're using probably has some way to open it.

When you open or extract the jar file you'll find the compiled class files in a directory structure that reflects your package structure.  For example, if you have Knight.java in the directory `src/game/characters/Knight.java` in the jar file you'll find something like `classes/game/characters/Knight.class`.

The name "jar" is an abbreviation of "Java archive".  It stores all the classes and other resources (for example, images) in a project.

Comment: another thing, I'm getting a "C:\Users\Jimmt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Game\nbproject\build-impl.xml:683: Existing manifest C:\Users\Jimmt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Game\build\null1407885333 is invalid" - could it be because I have classes I used in a different project?

Comment: I would post this as a new question and post the part of build-impl.xml that includes line 683. More information is needed to troubleshoot this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The classes you have defined in `.java` files will be compiled into `.class` files - these are contained in the `.jar` file.

Comment: Nope, the point of the .jar is to package your project together into one file that functions as an archive and can be run by the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

All resources get compiled into the JAR file. If you want a separate JAR for the resources, you'll need to split the project into two maven projects: one jar for the code, one for the resources. You can then create a third project that would generate a distribution.

That's a lot of work, though. It's.a lot easier tO keep everything in one JAR unless you have explicit dynamic loading requirements.